# SQL Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I'm receiving this syntax error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'DESC'

from this code

```
 $insert_status=mysql_query("INSERT INTO status(status, date) VALUES
                            ('$status','$date')") or die (mysql_error());
 $get_status= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM status WHERE id DESC")
               or die (mysql_error());
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($get_status)){
     $status=$row['status'];
     $date=$row['date'];
 }
```

Mysql version is 5.0.91-community

How can I resolve this small issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `id`? What does your table schema look like?

Comment: Hey Greg CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `status` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` text NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=31 ;

Comment: This is like a basic Facebook look alike Newsfeed, the id is the id for each comment. www.fightstar.org/test/wall.php

Comment: The SELECT statement is corrupt. It's missing a few bits. Name the "id" column should have an operator applied and "DESC" implies it's trying to order the results some way. See my answer below.

Comment: Thanks Xanadont, I shall give this ago and see what result is given. :)

Comment: @David If you're working through a number of problems and want help in real-time then I'd suggest heading over to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php

Answer (score 2):

WHERE id [...] DESC <- you need something in your where-clause AND you need to clarify what you're ordering on.  Something like:

```
select * from status where id in (1,2,3,4) order by id desc;
```

Comment: Such as 1 to maybe a 1000? Is there any shorter way than to add each and every number of the amount of comments that may and will be posted into the database under 'id'?

Comment: @David Draw: Do you even need a `where` clause at all?

Comment: @David Draw - yes. You can omit the WHERE and use `SELECT * FROM status ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100` to get the records with highest 100 ids.

Comment: It sounds like you may have a lack of understanding exactly what a SELECT statement does. I'm not trying to sound like a jerk, but you may want to learn about SELECT queries first - it looks to me like whatever's generating that SELECT statement (I'm assuming you didn't?) is missing some variables and not filling out the SELECT statement correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I was just posting an example of some valid statement that incorporated everything in the original statement. We have no idea exactly what the code's attempting w/o full context.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, my only issue now is that my inputted text is dissapearing after I refresh the page in my status box hmm. I don't know what to do or what I could be missing to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Galz or something like SELECT [...] WHERE id BETWEEN 101 AND 200 if paging is desired.

Comment: It is selecting the needed info from the database. 'ID' just I missed out some very important data that was needed to complete the statement. I am a learner yes, we all have to start somewhere, I'm used to HTML my than PHP and Mysql, but I'm trying to learn, and every bit of help goes into my brain with clear understanding. Crit is good and motivates me.

Comment: @xanadot - Maybe a matter of taste, but for paging I would use `LIMIT 100, 100` .. `LIMIT 200, 100` ... (as long as id is PK the performance would be the same)

Comment: http://www.fightstar.org/test/wall.php could you test this, I have a problem with the data being saved into the browser after refreshing the page. ;/ This I am struggling with.

Comment: If I had the cash I would do so Xanadont with great pleasure. I am working on a social networking site. Something like facebook but with a clear vision. I have set up the basic structure of the site and trying to do all the niggly bits. I'm no expert and I'm on a learning curve with lots of motivation. I have a dedicated server and I am hoping to go somewhere in the future. If only I could. :/

Comment: It would be nice to find a couple of very good coders that would code to make money in the long run rather than having to pay. Sort of like work towards the goal of how facebook came about. To some, its more effort than its worth.